# pyamf new Object types support

Tags: vector, amf, pyamf

pyamf supports object types
from

`TYPE_UNDEFINED = b'\x00' to TYPE_BYTEARRAY = b'\x0C'`

However new types were added accordingly to amf3 specification (January 2013):

```
undefined-marker=0x00 
null-marker=0x01 
false-marker=0x02 
true-marker=0x03 
integer-marker=0x04
double-marker=0x05 
string-marker=0x06 
xml-doc-marker=0x07 
date-marker=0x08 
array-marker=0x09 
object-marker=0x0A 
xml-marker=0x0B 
byte-array-marker=0x0C
vector-int-marker=0x0D
vector-uint-marker=0x0E
vector-double-marker=0x0F
vector-object-marker=0x10
dictionary-marker=0x11
```

Is there any support for new types at least to parse?